# Cannot accumulate heart rate data in Google Fit Api for the past week

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-api, heartrate

I am tyrying to grab the Heart Rate Summary for one week from the Google Api, but I get no result just the datatype name. If I grab only for a specific hour the Api return the heart rate grabbed from mi Mi Band 5 every 5 minutes or so. If anyone could help I would be grateful.

**Builder Function:**

```
private fun queryFitnessData2(): DataReadRequest {
    // [START build_read_data_request]
    // Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    val now = Date()
    
    calendar.time = now
    val endTime = calendar.timeInMillis
    calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1)
    val startTime = calendar.timeInMillis

    Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: ${dateFormat.format(startTime)}")
    Log.i(TAG, "Range End: ${dateFormat.format(endTime)}")

    return DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
             .enableServerQueries()
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
}
```

**Data Printer:**

```
 private fun printData(dataReadResult: DataReadResponse) {
        // [START parse_read_data_result]
        // If the DataReadRequest object specified aggregated data, dataReadResult will be returned
        // as buckets containing DataSets, instead of just DataSets.
        if (dataReadResult.buckets.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.buckets.size)
            for (bucket in dataReadResult.buckets) {
                bucket.dataSets.forEach { dumpDataSet(it) }
            }
        } else if (dataReadResult.dataSets.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.dataSets.size)
            dataReadResult.dataSets.forEach { dumpDataSet(it) }
        }
        // [END parse_read_data_result]
    }
```

**Dataset Parser Function:**

```
// [START parse_dataset]
    private fun dumpDataSet(dataSet: DataSet) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: ${dataSet.dataType.name}")
        val dateFormat: DateFormat = getTimeInstance()
        //THIS IS WHERE THE FOR LOOP DOESN'T WORK!!
        for (dp in dataSet.dataPoints) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Data point:")
            Log.i(TAG, "\tType: ${dp.dataType.name}")
            Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: ${dp.getStartTimeString()}")
            Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: ${dp.getEndTimeString()}")
            dp.dataType.fields.forEach {
                Log.i(TAG, "\tField: ${it.name} Value: ${dp.getValue(it)}")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END parse_dataset]
```

The only thing it gets logged is the data type which is the heart.rate.summary type.

Thefor loop doesn't work if I use the buckets for each day but works fine if I use them for each hour of the day. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to aggregate Heart Rate Data ( it works on my phone but not on the Android Studio's Emulator so have that in mind.
First add a data type for the heart rate and the aggregated heart rate:

```
FitnessOptions fitnessOptions =
    FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
        .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY,FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
        .build();
```

Then make the FitnessQuery Function as follows:

```
private fun queryFitnessData2(): DataReadRequest {
        // [START build_read_data_request]
        // Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
        val now = Date()

                calendar.time = now
        val endTime = calendar.timeInMillis
        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1)
        val startTime = calendar.timeInMillis

        Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: ${dateFormat.format(startTime)}")
        Log.i(TAG, "Range End: ${dateFormat.format(endTime)}")

        return DataReadRequest.Builder()

                 .enableServerQueries()
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
                .build();
}
```

And finally the dataset dump in buckets where each bucket corresponds to one day:

```
private fun printData(dataReadResult: DataReadResponse) {
        // [START parse_read_data_result]
        // If the DataReadRequest object specified aggregated data, dataReadResult will be returned
        // as buckets containing DataSets, instead of just DataSets.
        if (dataReadResult.buckets.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.buckets.size)
            for (i in 0 until dataReadResult.buckets.size) {

                for (j in 0 until dataReadResult.buckets[i].dataSets.size) {
                    dumpDataSet(dataReadResult.buckets[i].dataSets[j]);
                }
            }
        } else if (dataReadResult.dataSets.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Number of returned DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.dataSets.size)
            dataReadResult.dataSets.forEach { dumpDataSet(it) }
        }
        // [END parse_read_data_result]
    }

    // [START parse_dataset]
private fun dumpDataSet(dataSet: DataSet) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: ${dataSet.dataType.name}")
    val dateFormat: DateFormat = getTimeInstance()
    for (dp:DataPoint in dataSet.dataPoints) {
        Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
        Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.dataType.name);
        Log.i(TAG, "TEST")
        for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
            Log.i(TAG, "TEST4")
            val fieldValue = "Field name: " + field.name.toString() + ", value: " + dp.getValue(field).asFloat();
            Log.i(TAG, fieldValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope I helped anyone struggling with Google's horrible Api Documentation!